# Report on Cases and Approval steps

Tags: reporting, approval-step

We have implemented Approvals on Case Object with multiple steps.
Our requirement is to analyze the number of Cases at each step of the approval process. How should I go about doing this

> Is there a report I can use - I did try finding  it but could not see any options for that
>
> Can I capture if on case by creating a field ?

Pls advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for [Approval History Reports](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approval_history_reports.htm&type=5)

> If you create a custom report type for approval process instances, users can view the historical details of completed and in-progress approval processes and their individual steps.

You will need to [Create a Custom Report Type for Approval History](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approval_history_custom_report_type.htm&type=5) to be able to report on it.